# Howto create css columns that incl. a scrollable middle column and floating left and right columns

Tags: css, css-float

I'm creating a webpage where I need a content column in the center of the page (including a fixed width) and two non-scrollable (fixed) columns at the left and the right side of that content column (including a fixed width also). The left column needs to be aligned to the left side of the middle content column. The right column needs to be aligned to the right side of the middle content column. 
If the content column gets a lot of content the middle content column should be scrollable with a scrollbar at the right side of the browser. But the left and right columns must not scroll, but stay fixed against the top of the browser.
When resizing the browser width then the left+middle+right columns keeps their width and centered in the middle of the webpage. At the left side of the left column and at the right side of the right column the whitespace will increase/decrease on both sides with same width.

In my screen example you find the concept of what I'm trying to solve.
[image: screen example]

I tried to search for this problem at stackoverflow and google, but I only found examples wich are a bit different.

Who knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**example in JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/ahiha4) 
 - (see updated version below, this is buggy, fixed columns are sticky)

- the green is not required it's there
  to show the wrapper is actually
  centering the whole lot
- absolutely
  position the left and right wraps
  first so the the `position:fixed`
  columns don't go to side of viewport

#### Update

non-buggy version now in **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ahiha4/2)**

hmm that was more difficult than I thought it would be; this one works in IE7, 8, Safari, FF3.6, Opera, Chrome

view the source code for the notes, especially interesting is pointer-events, without them the newer browsers will not click through (select text or click a link) an "overlaid" div, which is what this layout is doing it's overlaying an Absolutely Position div and using absolute positioning and relative position to get around the scrolling, vertical and horizontal, issues there was with disappearing content and sticky fixed divs

#### Updated to use jQuery as per comments

**Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/kuYkE/)**

Comment: actually that's a bit buggy, right column is sticking under right side of window if it's narrowed too much.. even with a min-width on the body

Comment: second version should work better, previous comment applies to first version which is left in for reference

Comment: Works great! Damn, i was trying to solve this issue for hours. Great job!

I have no IE6 on my machines. Do you know this works also under IE6, or is there a fix for it?

Comment: yep seems to work fine in ie6 too :) & you're welcome, I like a challenge! - I originally thought fixed divs were the answer, but they didn't work too well and they wouldn't have worked in IE6 anyway ;)

Comment: Cool! Just tested in IE9, works also perfect! One more question, when you resize the width of the browser to a smaller width then the min-width of the body (css), then the vertical scrollbar will hide at the right side of the browser. Is it also possible to show this scroller always, even when you change the width of the browser to a very small width? I'm using a scroll wheel on my mouse, but if you don't have this scroll wheel, and your browser width is very small, you will not be able to scroll down (if the vertical scroller is hidden).

Comment: I've just tried your first version. This one seems to work also good, right? When you resize the browser width to smaller width then the min-width, it will show the vertical scrollbar always at the right side of the browser (it will not be hidden, like it does in the 2nd version). Does this version also work properly under IE6 and IE7 ?

Comment: hi Guido, yes I noticed that, up/down arrows work as well - not ideal :( it's because the scroll bar is not actually on the `body` element anymore, you can change the min-width for both the `body` & the `#content-wrap` to `970px` - (or 30px more than you need). This just gives both of them enough room to show the scrollbar - you still have to horizontal scroll right to get to the vertical scroll bar, but the best I can think of

Comment: with the first version when you horizontal scroll the two side columns go out of view and stick there, I didn't think that would be very desirable - yes the vertical scroll is still there because it's on the `body` element didn't even test it in IE6 it was "sticky" in every browser I did try in including IE7/8

Comment: or rather the right column gets lost the left overlaps, but does go back to it's place

Comment: if you think the first version will do, I see the right column comes back when you put the browser back to full size (or bigger than the min-width) - let me know I'll test it in IE6, but it will be tomorrow now am off out

Comment: Ok, i didn't noticed the issue in version 1 and it isn't desirable. But is there a certain way to keep the vertical scroller of version 2 in the viewport all time?

Comment: yes/no, but it's not ideally perfect, see my comment about 5 up from this (the one about increasing the min-width) - we cross posted LOL.. BUT not all the time because that would mean the body was then doing the scrolling, which would mean the side columns will scroll too - sorry, I'll try a bit more on it tomorrow to see if there's another way but I think that's the best of the two worlds?

Comment: I understand. Actually, the point was that i have a content column of 600px and a left and right column of 250px both, including a spacing of 20px between the content column and the left + right column. In total this shows a total of 1140px. Only if a user has a screen of 1024px he should see the vertical scroller immediately. So that is actually the reason to want this scroller always showed at the right side of the browser screen. But if there is no other solution, i have no other option ofcourse :-) Anyway, i really appreciate your help!

Comment: just to say Hi, I'm not ignoring this, I did have another go, but reaching the same issues, I can get the vertical scrollbar to always show but fixed content in the sidebars will always "stick" **under** the right side of the viewport unless the window is wide enough to show it, it's the nature of `position: fixed`  - I think JS (to get the smooth fixed sidebar content) with a fallback to `position: absolute` (where the sides will scroll with the content) for non-JS users may be the only option, do you want to use jQuery/JS?

Comment: Hi Clairesuzy, sorry for my late responce.. I was out of town for a while. Yes, i love to use jQuery/JS. Is it fixable with jQuery do you think? Regards, Guido

Comment: @Guido Lemmens 2, now my turn to apologize.. yes it's would be possible, [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/kuYkE/) - done with jQuery -  does it **but** not very smoothly, it falls back to `position: absolute;` when no jquery and if you animate the scroll function you can make it smoother or there are plugins